# Error 127 make file error using qt plugin

Tags: eclipse, qt, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse CDT and I have installed a Qt plugin in it. I have imported a Qt project using the Qt plugin, the project was building fine earlier when I used Qt 4.8 but now it is giving a build error:

> Make error 127

I have checked everything from flags to libraries to includes still error is persistent.

Comment: Did you just change Qt, or also the compiler used? Are you sure all paths are set correctly?

Comment: @Bart its the same compiler gcc 4.6.1

Comment: Hmm, okay. Because AFAIK error 127 usually indicates that Make itself is not found.